# pandas hist method returns an empty plot with different layout settings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, histogram

I have the following code to create historgram for each column in the dataframe. There are in total 17 columns and I want to produce their histograms in 4 columns by 5 rows.

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('BLK0_')].hist(xlabelsize=8, 
                                                   ylabelsize=8, 
                                                   layout=(4,5))
plt.show()
```

However, this returns an empty window. When I create a layout that perfectly fits the number of histograms (17), then it works: 1 row and 17 columns, or 17 rows and 1 column..

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('BLK0_')].hist(xlabelsize=8, 
                                                   ylabelsize=8, 
                                                   layout=(1,17))
                                                   #or (17,1)
plt.show()
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue? I need to have the histograms in 4 columns.

Here is the summary of the data:

```
count   410.000000  410.000000  410.000000  410.000000  410.000000  410.000000  410.000000  410.000000
mean    0.504878    0.026829    0.239024    0.090244    0.126829    0.129268    0.314634    0.158537
std     0.638018    0.161782    0.649573    0.355402    0.488010    0.414141    0.797938    0.520239
min     0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
25%     0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
50%     0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
75%     1.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
max     4.000000    1.000000    5.000000    3.000000    6.000000    3.000000    5.000000    5.000000
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ would the summary of the data help?